# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException while using user defined annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I am getting null pointer exception while executing following method. I have debugged and found that `cons.getAnnotation(MyAssessment.class);` is returning `null`. Plese help

```
import java.lang.annotation.*; 
import java.lang.reflect.*; 

enum GradeLevel { POOR, AVERAGE, GOOD, VERYGOOD, EXTRAORDINARY }

@interface MyAssessment {
    GradeLevel score();
}

public class Problem {

    @MyAssessment(score=GradeLevel.GOOD)
    public Problem(){
        System.out.println("This is a constuructor");
    }

    public static void main(String... args){

        try {
            Class c = new Problem().getClass();
            Constructor cons = c.getDeclaredConstructor();
            MyAssessment an = (MyAssessment) cons.getAnnotation(MyAssessment.class);
            System.out.println("YOUR SCORE IS : " + an.score());
        }
        catch(NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
            System.out.println("Constructor thrown exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotations are not by default available at runtime.  You need to annotate your annotation :P

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface MyAssessment {
```

You can also add a `@Target` of say `CONSTRUCTOR` to say it should only appear on constructors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate your annotation with:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Retention Policy of your annotation. Using @Retention.